# CSV File Modifications

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm having a little trouble figure out this problem and I was looking for a little help.

I want to do two things:

- Add two more header column headers to the existing ones (`Mon_diff`, `c_risk`)
- Compare a date in the `e_enddt` column to today and print the month difference
  (ex. today() > 6/30/2017 = output would be '3' as in 3 months.

The existing data looks like this.

Can anyone suggest what would be the best way to accomplish this. I've been reading about both pandas and csv.

Comment: And the new `c_risk` columns should be blank..?

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Have you attempted anything? If so, how did it not work out? What is your question?

Comment: Im not asking for you to write my code. Im asking for suggestions on the best way to do this. Ive been reading a lot.

Comment: Open the input file for reading and create a `csv.reader` object. Open an output file for writing and create a `csv.writer` object. Read each line of the input file, process the data, and write one line of the output file. You should be able do the date-related stuff by using the `datetime` module. This will require you to convert the string values the `csv.reader` will return into `date` or datetime` object first.

Comment: @Anthony If you don't answer people's simple follow-up questions then nobody is going to do you the service of answering yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just a beginner who got into CSV file input very recently (I would import a modified CSV Excel File and plot the averages of the data on a graph). As what I did, I would recommend storing all your data in a list (if not already):

each row is a separate list, which is enclosed in a large list, something like this (watch out with the indenting):

```
myData = [['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'], # Row 1
          [9,2,3],                           # Row 2
          [3,4,2],                           # Row 3
          [5,2,0]                            # Row 4
]
```

So you can easily acess data with list indexing, such as:

```
print(myData[1][0])
```

Which should return 9.

Based on this, you can create functions that suit your demands.

To answer your questions, these would be my suggestions:

**I - HOW TO ADD EXTRA COLUMNS**

1.1 To add a header, create a function that appends an additional value from a list to the end of the main list (myData in this case).

1.2 Then, create a function to print out all the data with tab spacing ( '\t').

**II - HOW TO COMPARE DATES IN DD/MM/YYYY FORMAT**

2. This is trickier, but using the .split() method would be interesting. After storing the data from .split('/') in a list, you can also use list indexing to figure out the difference.

I do hope my beginner advice and experience will help you!